"Time Machine" outcome with special summoned monster - a scenario
I'm playing Yu-Gi-Oh!1 and I have a doubt about the following scenario:

Turn 3 - my turn - and in my field I have the following cards:


Chimeratech Overdragon (face-up in attack position) - (it was properly special summoned).
Time Machine (trap card - set in previous turn).

My opponent has on the field:

Dark Magician (face-up in attack position) = ATK: 2500
Forbidden Chalice - (it can be activated)


My play:


Attack with "Chimeratech Overdragon" = ATK: 4000 to Dark Magician = ATK: 2500


My opponent:


Activates "Forbidden Chalice" to "Chimeratech Overdragon".
"Chimeratech Overdragon" has his effects negated = ATK: ?

After this battle, I receive 2500 LP and "Chimeratech Overdragon" is destroyed and sent to the graveyard.
However, I activate "Time Machine" - in order to get back "Chimeratech Overdragon" on my field (and attack again to Dark Magician - if "Chimeratech Overdragon" has its original ATK/DEF 4000 ATK that has before being destroyed by having its effects negated).
Issue: Since "Forbidden Chalice" was activated, "Chimeratech Overdragon" would have its effects negated, making his ATK back to ?, then, destroyed by attacking a monster with higher ATK. I activate "Time Machine" for bring back "Chimeratech Fortress Dragon" and - since it was summoned as required, "Chimeratech Overdragon" should have the ATK of 4000 that it has before being destroyed (since its original ATK was changed by his own effect when it was special summoned).
Is my line of thought correct?
I've searched on yugioh wikia and in ygoresources.com, but, I'm not sure what the outcome will be in this situation.
Links:

Time Machine - ygoresources.com
Chimeratech Overdragon - ygoresources.com
Time Machine - yugioh.wikia.com - here is says:

Quote:

Use this card to revive monsters that could be summoned without
Tributes and thus had lower stats as a result of being summoned this
way (such as "Fusilier Dragon, the Dual-Mode Beast" or "Beast King
Barbaros"). They will be revived with their original stats.

Given that the bolding section states about the original stats and "Chimeratech Overdragon" has its original ATK/DEF set by their own effect, I'm consufed whether about this interaction.
I found no other precedents and the quoted paragraph looks to me like a contradiction for this scenario.

1 Currently playing Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 5 (and I want to try the described play on this game), but I'm looking for answers that applies to this version of the game as well for Yu-Gi-Oh! Master Duel, Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links and the TCG.

You can't do that. "Chimeratech Overdragon" states:

Must be Fusion Summoned.

"Time machine" doesn't fusion summon, so you can't bring "Chimeratech Overdragon" with it. And if you could, it would have an atk of 0 as it would be special summoned and not fusion summoned (with no material, on top of that).

About the confusion on the tips for "Time Machine", here's what it means:

Normal summon "Fusilier Dragon, the Dual-Mode Beast" with no tribute. Its original ATK becomes halved (1400) while face-up on the field.
"Fusilier Dragon, the Dual-Mode Beast" is destroyed by battle and sent to the GY, at this point all effects on it, including the change to its original ATK, stop applying.
Use "Time Machine" to special summon "Fusilier Dragon, the Dual-Mode Beast" back. As it is special summoned and not normal summoned with no tribute, its effect doesn't apply and it keeps its original ATK of 2800.

